# Should webmasters "index" dashboard and edit account page

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engine-indexing

New here, I did my research and found nothing, but sorry if it has already been asked.

As webmasters should be let google and other search engine INDEX our member's dashboard and edit account page.

For example my member John has access to a page name "Edit your account" where he can fill some fields and updates his info.
Or another pages where John can manage his posts (edit, delete)

Such pages have no interest to the other people so should be let google and others INDEX it or should we NOINDEX it ?

Thanks for your time !
Franck

Comment: If your member dashboard and edit account pages require a log in, as it likely does, then search engines won't be able to log in, and consequently can't index account pages.

Comment: Well as simple as it is I never thought about that...
Thanks for the reply and sorry for newbie question...

Comment: No worries - feel free to ask other questions on this site, and review the other ones too...everyone has to start somewhere :-)

Comment: @dan that's not 100% true. Just because a members area requires a login doesn't mean it can't be indexed. I've seen it happen to some web apps. How exactly they manage to configure their app to let Google in is beyond me, but it has happened. So code with care, and assume Google will find everything on your website and take precautions from the moment you put your website online

Comment: @Anagio Should we assume that our StackExchange member account pages can be indexed then? ;-) I think that depends on what log in approach is used, but in general, legit search engines don't enter usernames and passwords...

Answer (score 1):

**Do not index them**, those pages are not relevant for SERPs, there are hundreds of pages more relevant for people searching your site than *Edit Your Profile* or similar pages.

It's true that users need to log in before accessing to those pages, but Google can crawl and actually index something like "*You need rights to access this page*" unless you make sure you place `nofollow` to all of the links pointing there, maybe add it to your robots.txt, etc.

So to avoid all that, place a `noindex` meta tag and you won't have to worry about it any more.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answer I did a beautiful NOINDEX on these pages, better be safe than sorry .